# Calling a function without all the given arguments

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the following syntax. Why is it allowed to pass in arguments that are less than the given outcome? For example,

```
def fit_curve_custom(f, xdata, ydata, p0=None, sigma=None, **kwargs):
   po, pc = curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, **kwargs)

def fit(x, a, b, c):
   return a*exp(b)+c

(po, pun, rac, de) = fit_curve_custom(fit, xsamples, yobserved)
```

In the above code `fit_curve_custom` has six arguments however when it is called later there are only three arguments passed and yet it still behaves as expected? Does this syntax actually have a name? Also, the function `fit` has four parameters and yet when it is called in `fit_curve_custom` no parameters are passed? Why is that possible?

Comment: See [More on defining functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions) in the standard tutorial.

Comment: The syntax is called a function having default arguments. Also, `fit_curve_custom ` _doesn't_ call the `fit()` function.

Comment: @martineau What do you mean that it doesn't call the fit function? the fit function is passed in the `fit_curve_custom` function

Comment: @tdelaney that link helps, ty

Comment: There is no call to the passed `fit()` function in the `fit_curve_custom()` function.

Comment: You have 2 questions here: 1 is defining optional parameters for a function, 1 is how to *__pass__* functions as arguments to another function.

Answer (score 1):

```
fit_curve_custom(fit, xsamples, yobserved)
```

This is possible because the last two parameters of `fit_curve_custom` are `optional argument` or `named arguments`

If there are not passed the will have an default value
p0=None, sigma=None

The last `kwargs` is a keyword arguments which is python convention that allows passing into function a `dict` of named argument, inside the function they can be accessed `kwargs['arg1']`

for example :

```
fit_curve_custom(fit, xsamples, yobserved, p1 = None, sigma = None, arg1 = 'a', arg2 = 'b')
```

In `fit_curve_custom(fit, xsamples, yobserved)`, `fit` here is actually not called, it is passed to `fit_curve_custom` function ( functions can be passed as regular values) and the be called, like :

```
def fit_curve_custom(f, xdata, ydata, p0=None, sigma=None, **kwargs):
   calc_res = f(10, 10, 10, 10) #  call f
   po, pc = curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, **kwargs) #  f is passed to another function
```